# Braid collapsed to 2 distinguished points

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, knot-theory, braid-groups

> Is there a study of non crossing paths from point A to point B in 3-space?
> Could be braid theory but in that theory the strands don't all converge to the same point(s).

The idea is equivalent to taking an arbitrary braid and collapsing the distinguished points down to exactly 2 points.

With the quotient however, you'd lose the permutation structure that is an important characteristic of the braid group.

Comment: Braids have an additional requirement that they "never double back on themselves" (this can be characterized rigorously, of course). Otherwise you're looking at a class of *tangles*. Do you intend for the braid condition to hold?

Comment: Just a note: If you collapse the two ends of a braid to a point, then any braid can be unwound and is therefore trivial. Also another thing you'd lose besides the permutation structure is the group or monoid structure since you can no longer compose objects to get an object of the same kind.

Comment: @SammyBlack yes i intend for the braid condition to hold

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I guess i wanted that you could not unwind like you say, and that the braids are firmly anchored at the two points

Comment: @Geocalc33, one possibility is to fix the tangent vector of a strand at each point.